# Maven pom.xml, SCM and release

Tags: maven, release, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

I want to do a mvn release:prepare, that will remove the "-SNAPSHOT" from the version and tag it in SVN.

I have these settings in pom.xml:

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:http://subversion.local:3690/svn/projects/x/trunk</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://subversion.local:3690/svn/projects/x/tags</developerConnection>
  <url>scm:svn:http://subversion.loi.local:3690/svn/projects/x/tags</url>
 </scm>
```

But these does not behave like i wanted. Instead it gets everything from /tags are re-tags it under /tags.

So again, what i want, take from HEAD, drop "-SNAPSHOT" and tag it under /tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<scm>` tag denotes read-only connection configuration ("connection" element), read-write connection ("developerConnection") and publicly visible URL. It does not have anything to do with tagging. In a small local network it's common for these 3 parameters to be the same.

For tag base, you need to configure the release plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <tagBase>scm:svn:http://subversion.local:3690/svn/projects/x/tags</tagBase>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

just wanted to say that the tagBase parameter is just relevant for SVN!
(CVS doesn't use it eg.)

Answer (score 1):

I am using maven-release-plugin successfully with the `developerConnection` pointing to trunk.

When preparing a release the tag is created under the `/tags` directory (the plugin also updates `connection` and `developerConnection` in the pom.xml of the tag.

Comment: You are right, but when I am trying to execute release:perform its failure.It shows there is no pom.xml in side the target dir.Can you help me out.